# Find Duplicate names from SQL table with Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find duplicate names from a SQL Table using the Primary key or Identity Column.

I have three columns: ID, FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR.

I'm retrieving data using the following query:

```
SELECT FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR, COUNT(*)
FROM Persons
GROUP BY FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The result of this query is I am getting count of duplicate names but I am not getting its ID.

I need ID of duplicate names.

Comment: Hopefully this will lead someone to create the proper constraint to enforce uniqueness of the 2 names. A synthetic primary key does not relieve the dba from identifying and enforcing natural keys.

Answer (score 3):

Just join it back to your table:

```
SELECT  P.* 
FROM    Persons AS P
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT FirstNameAR
                ,       SecondNameAR
                FROM    Persons
                GROUP BY FirstNameAR
                ,       SecondNameAR
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
            ) AS DUB
        ON  DUB.FirstNameAR = P.FirstNameAR
        AND DUB.SecondNameAR = P.SecondNameAR
```

Comment: This. In situations where you have such a problem, it's useful to break your problem down into simple parts. You need to do two things: get the duplicates, then get the ID of the duplicates. So you need to perform two queries and join them.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use count as a window function:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id
         , FirstNameAR
         , SecondNameAR
         , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR) As Cnt
    FROM Persons
)

SELECT  Id
      , FirstNameAR
      , SecondNameAR
      , Cnt As [Number of duplicates]
FROM CTE
WHERE Cnt > 1
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR,COUNT(*), string_agg(id,',')
FROM Persons
GROUP BY FirstNameAR, SecondNameAR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Try this one if you use SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server Vnext, SQL Azure:)